# TypeError: Cannot read property 'coverNaming' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am writing unit test for reactjs web application using mocha,chai and enzyme .. I am often getting this error..

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'coverNaming' of undefined   at
>   Cover.render (src/components/cover.js:31:30)

Here's my code in cover.js

```
    let signatureEco = this.state.signatureEcoCoverType;    
    let secondColor = this.state.secondColor;    
    let catalogSubCategory = this.props.catalogType;    
    let namingVisibility=catalogSubCategory.coverNaming;
```

Next error I often  get is

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>    at Papertype.render
>   (src/components/layoutcomponents/papertype.js:50:23)

Here is code in **papertype.js**

```
    let validLayoutPaperType=this.props.validLayoutPaperType;
    let paperTypeOptions = [];    
    let paperTypeOpts = common.paperTypeOpts;    
    for(let i=0;i<validLayoutPaperType.length;i++){    
       let paper = paperTypeOpts[validLayoutPaperType[i]]    
       paperTypeOptions.push(<option label={paper}                 
       value={paper} key={i}>{paper}</option>)
    }
```

I don't get errors  while running the application , it only happens when i run test .. basically i have written snapshot test for now.

Comment: When you have errors that happen only in testing but not when you actually run the app, or vice-versa, that's often a sign that you're not handling an asynchronous operation correctly. To get a precise answer, you have to provide us with a [mcve]. What you have in your question right now does not show how you get your data (we don't see how `this.state` is created/manipulated, same for `this.props` in the 2nd error.

Comment: Sir can i mail you my code ..? Can you please give your mail id ..